# Pros and cons of JWE Key Management Modes

Tags: security, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, key-management, jwe

I've been searching a lot but nothing hit the spot, they are questions about JWE key management.

**Scenario**:

Server wants to send sensitive data to client, and it chooses to encrypt the data with a symmetric algorithm by a symmetric key, i.e, Content Encryption Key (CEK).
Client will retrieve the CEK to decrypt the encrypted data, but the CEK can't be sent as a clear text together with the encrypted data, so the CEK will need to be encrypted.

**Approach**:

The JWE specification defines different key management modes as follows

1. Key Wrapping: the CEK is encrypted for the intended recipient using a symmetric encryption algorithm.
   [Key Wrapping Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6730v.jpg)
2. Key Encryption: the CEK is encrypted for the intended recipient using an asymmetric encryption algorithm.
   [Key Encryption Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezN8K.jpg)
3. Direct Key Agreement: a key agreement algorithm is used to pick the CEK.
   [Direct Key Agreement Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1npCZ.jpg)
4. Key Agreement with Key Wrapping: a key agreement algorithm is used to pick a
   symmetric CEK using a symmetric encryption algorithm.
   [Key Agreement with Key Wrapping Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hoxT.jpg)
5. Direct Encryption: a user-defined symmetric shared key is used as the CEK (no key derivation or generation).
   [Direct Encryption Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp4h9.jpg)

**Question**:

1. What are pros and cons of each mode?
2. Under what circumstance will each mode be preferable?

Any help or advise would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: There is no pros or cons with JWE Key Management Modes.
The applicable mode only depends on the key encryption algorithm. You don't have to make a choice between those wodes…

Comment: https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/advanced-topics/encrypted-tokens-and/multiple-recipients#key-management-modes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are JWE Key Management Modes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74259219/what-are-jwe-key-management-modes)

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74259220/823371) for the difference between the key management modes and when to use each.