# What are JWE Key Management Modes?

Tags: jwe

The [JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) standard defines a concept called ***Key Management Mode***. According to the RFC, there are five: Direct Encryption, Key Encryption, Direct Key Agreement, Key Wrapping, Key Agreement with Key Wrapping.

What's the difference between them and what's the point of having so many?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**JWE** always encrypts plaintext using a symmetric encryption key called `CEK` (Content Encryption Key). An issuer and recipient don't always have a pre-shared key they can use as the `CEK`, so they must use some form of public-key cryptography in order to securely share or agree on a `CEK` to use. **Key Management Modes** specify how the `CEK` is determined.

**JWE** always provides ***confidentiality*** (ensure only recipient can decrypt data), and ***integrity*** (ensure data was not altered by a third-party during transit). Depending on the **Key Management Mode**, it can also provide ***authentication*** (ensure data comes from issuer it claims to be).

**JWE** also supports tokens intended for multiple recipients where each recipient may use a different **Key Management Mode**. In this scenario, the **JWE** cannot use [compact serialization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-3.1) and must use [JSON serialization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-3.2). Additionally, regardless of the number of recipients, **JWE** uses a single `CEK` to encrypt the plaintext. Thus, there is no need to include a different copy of the ciphertext for each intended recipient.

The following are the supported **Key Management Modes** by **JWE**:

**1. Direct Encryption:**

- **Used when:**

  - Issuer and recipient have a pre-shared symmetric key.
- **How it works:**

  - Let the pre-shared symmetric key be the `CEK`.
  - Issuer encrypts plaintext with `CEK`.
  - Recipient decrypts ciphertext with `CEK`.
- **Properties:**

  - Confidentiality.
  - Integrity.
  - Authentication (assuming only issuer and recipient have knowledge of `CEK`).
- **Supported by multi-recipient JWE:** No.
- **Example JOSE header:** `{ "alg": "dir", "enc": "A256GCM" }`

**2. Key Encryption:**

- **Used when:**

  - **Scenario A:**

    - Issuer and recipient do not have a pre-shared symmetric key.
    - Issuer has knowledge of a recipient's public `RSA` key.
  - **Scenario B:**

    - Issuer wants to send a single **JWE** to multiple recipients.
    - Issuer and at least one of the recipients do not have a pre-shared symmetric key. Instead, the issuer has knowledge of a public `RSA` key for that recipient.
- **How it works:**

  - Issuer randomly-generates a `CEK`.
  - Issuer encrypts plaintext with `CEK`.
  - For each intended recipient:

    - Issuer encrypts `CEK` with recipient's public key.
    - Issuer includes encrypted `CEK` + ciphertext in **JWE**.
    - Recipient decrypts encrypted `CEK` with its private key.
    - Recipient decrypts ciphertext with `CEK`.
- **Properties:**

  - Confidentiality.
  - Integrity.
- **Supported by multi-recipient JWE:** Yes.
- **Example JOSE header:** `{ "alg": "RSA-OAEP", "enc": "A256GCM" }`

**3. Direct Key Agreement**

- **Used when:**

  - The issuer and recipient do not have a pre-shared symmetric key.
  - Issuer has knowledge of a recipient's public `EC` key (`EC` key pairs cannot be used directly to encrypt/decrypt data).
- **How it works:**

  - Issuer randomly-generates an ephemeral `EC` public/private key pair.
  - Issuer derives `CEK` using ephemeral private key and recipient's public key.
  - Issuer encrypts plaintext with `CEK`.
  - Issuer includes ephemeral public key + ciphertext in **JWE**.
  - Recipient derives `CEK` using ephemeral public key and its private key.
  - Recipient decrypts ciphertext with `CEK`.
- **Properties:**

  - Confidentiality.
  - Integrity.
- **Supported by multi-recipient JWE:** No.
- **Example JOSE header:** `{ "alg": "ECDH-ES", "enc": "A256GCM", "epk": { ephemeral public key }, "apu": "(issuer)", "apv": "(recipient)" }`

**4. Key Wrapping**

- **Used when:**

  - The issuer wants to send a single **JWE** to multiple recipients.
  - The issuer and at least one of the recipients have a pre-shared secret.
- **How it works:**

  - Issuer randomly-generates a `CEK`.
  - Issuer encrypts plaintext with `CEK`.
  - For each intended recipient:

    - Let the pre-shared secret be the wrapping key or a password used to derive a wrapping key.
    - Issuer encrypts `CEK` with the wrapping key.
    - Issuer includes encrypted `CEK` + ciphertext in **JWE**.
    - Recipient finds its corresponding encrypted `CEK` and decrypts it with the wrapping key.
    - Recipient decrypts ciphertext with `CEK`.
- **Properties:**

  - Confidentiality.
  - Integrity.
  - Authentication (assuming only issuer and recipient have knowledge of shared secret).
- **Supported by multi-recipient JWE:** Yes.
- **Example JOSE header:** `{ "alg": "A256KW", "enc": "A256GCM" }`

**5. Key Agreement with Key Wrapping**

- **Used when:**

  - The issuer wants to send a single **JWE** to multiple recipients.
  - The issuer and at least one of the recipients do not have a pre-shared symmetric key. Instead, the issuer has knowledge of a public `EC` key for that recipient (`EC` key pairs cannot be used directly to encrypt/decrypt data).
- **How it works:**

  - Issuer randomly-generates a `CEK`.
  - Issuer encrypts plaintext with `CEK`.
  - For each intended recipient:

    - Issuer randomly-generates an ephemeral `EC` public/private key pair.
    - Issuer derives a wrapping key using ephemeral private key and recipient's public key.
    - Issuer encrypts `CEK` using wrapping key.
    - Issuer includes encrypted `CEK` + ephemeral public key + ciphertext in **JWE**.
    - Recipient finds its corresponding ephemeral public key and derives wrapping key using it and its private key.
    - Recipient finds its corresponding encrypted `CEK` and decrypts it using the derived wrapping key.
    - Recipient decrypts ciphertext with `CEK`.
- **Properties:**

  - Confidentiality.
  - Integrity.
- **Supported by multi-recipient JWE:** Yes.
- **Example JOSE header:** `{ "alg": "ECDH-ES+A256KW", "enc": "A256GCM", "epk": { ephemeral public key }, "apu": "(issuer)", "apv": "(recipient)" }`

Comment: This is very helpful. The RFC itself does not explain this well.

Answer (score 0):

7518 JSON Web Algorithms (JWA) includes details on [Cryptographic Algorithms for Key Management](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#page-12). As to why so many, the JWA model use cases are wide and the RFC states:

> Registering the algorithms and identifiers here, rather than in the
> JWS, JWE, and JWK specifications, is intended to allow them to remain
> unchanged in the face of changes in the set of Required, Recommended,
> Optional, and Deprecated algorithms over time.  This also allows
> changes to the JWS, JWE, and JWK specifications without changing this
> document.

> The table below is the set of "alg" (algorithm) Header Parameter
> values that are defined by this specification for use with JWE.
> These algorithms are used to encrypt the CEK, producing the JWE
> Encrypted Key, or to use key agreement to agree upon the CEK.

```
   +--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+
   | "alg" Param Value  | Key Management     | More   | Implementation |
   |                    | Algorithm          | Header | Requirements   |
   |                    |                    | Params |                |
   +--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+
   | RSA1_5             | RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5   | (none) | Recommended-   |
   | RSA-OAEP           | RSAES OAEP using   | (none) | Recommended+   |
   |                    | default parameters |        |                |
   | RSA-OAEP-256       | RSAES OAEP using   | (none) | Optional       |
   |                    | SHA-256 and MGF1   |        |                |
   |                    | with SHA-256       |        |                |
   | A128KW             | AES Key Wrap with  | (none) | Recommended    |
   |                    | default initial    |        |                |
   |                    | value using        |        |                |
   |                    | 128-bit key        |        |                |
   | A192KW             | AES Key Wrap with  | (none) | Optional       |
   |                    | default initial    |        |                |
   |                    | value using        |        |                |
   |                    | 192-bit key        |        |                |
   | A256KW             | AES Key Wrap with  | (none) | Recommended    |
   |                    | default initial    |        |                |
   |                    | value using        |        |                |
   |                    | 256-bit key        |        |                |
   | dir                | Direct use of a    | (none) | Recommended    |
   |                    | shared symmetric   |        |                |
   |                    | key as the CEK     |        |                |
   | ECDH-ES            | Elliptic Curve     | "epk", | Recommended+   |
   |                    | Diffie-Hellman     | "apu", |                |
   |                    | Ephemeral Static   | "apv"  |                |
   |                    | key agreement      |        |                |
   |                    | using Concat KDF   |        |                |
   | ECDH-ES+A128KW     | ECDH-ES using      | "epk", | Recommended    |
   |                    | Concat KDF and CEK | "apu", |                |
   |                    | wrapped with       | "apv"  |                |
   |                    | "A128KW"           |        |                |
   | ECDH-ES+A192KW     | ECDH-ES using      | "epk", | Optional       |
   |                    | Concat KDF and CEK | "apu", |                |
   |                    | wrapped with       | "apv"  |                |
   |                    | "A192KW"           |        |                |
   | ECDH-ES+A256KW     | ECDH-ES using      | "epk", | Recommended    |
   |                    | Concat KDF and CEK | "apu", |                |
   |                    | wrapped with       | "apv"  |                |
   |                    | "A256KW"           |        |                |
   | A128GCMKW          | Key wrapping with  | "iv",  | Optional       |
   |                    | AES GCM using      | "tag"  |                |
   |                    | 128-bit key        |        |                |
   | A192GCMKW          | Key wrapping with  | "iv",  | Optional       |
   |                    | AES GCM using      | "tag"  |                |
   |                    | 192-bit key        |        |                |
   | A256GCMKW          | Key wrapping with  | "iv",  | Optional       |
   |                    | AES GCM using      | "tag"  |                |
   |                    | 256-bit key        |        |                |
   | PBES2-HS256+A128KW | PBES2 with HMAC    | "p2s", | Optional       |
   |                    | SHA-256 and        | "p2c"  |                |
   |                    | "A128KW" wrapping  |        |                |
   | PBES2-HS384+A192KW | PBES2 with HMAC    | "p2s", | Optional       |
   |                    | SHA-384 and        | "p2c"  |                |
   |                    | "A192KW" wrapping  |        |                |
   | PBES2-HS512+A256KW | PBES2 with HMAC    | "p2s", | Optional       |
   |                    | SHA-512 and        | "p2c"  |                |
   |                    | "A256KW" wrapping  |        |                |
   +--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+
```